# Is there any work in English that gives a systematic treatment of Soviet/Russian rocket engines?

Tags: rockets, history, russia, soviet-union

There seems to be some piecemeal information online such as *RussianSpaceWeb.com*, and of course, Sutton's *History of LPRE* gives an anthropological treatment of Soviet/Russian rocket engine lineup without providing a lot of detail about them. Is there any work in English that discuss them from a more technological perspective? They have some very interesting engines that have no western equivalent, e.g. ORSC engine that runs on UDMH/NTO, not to mention producing nearly all the closed-cycle engines.

Comment: I love Anatoly Zak's book that is based on RussianSpaceWeb.com but Ii wish he had organized it different or at least had a appendix listing the boosters with common performance metrics and same for engines.  As they are scattered throughout the book and hard to compare.